# Understanding Read instance

Tags: parsing, haskell

I made `Read` and `Show` instances of my data, but did not understand the `Read` instance

```
data Tests = Zero
          | One Int
          | Two Int Double

instance Show Tests where
  show Zero      = "ZERO"
  show (One i)   = printf "ONE %i" i
  show (Two i j) = printf "TWO %i %f" i j

instance Read Tests where
  readsPrec _ str   = [(mkTests str, "")]

mkTests :: String -> Tests
mkTests = check . words

check :: [String] -> Tests
check ["ZERO"]      = Zero
check ["ONE", i]    = One (read i)
check ["TWO", i, j] = Two (read i) (read j)
check _             = error "no parse"

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print Zero
  print $ One 10
  print $ Two 1 3.14

  let x = read "ZERO" :: Tests
  print x
  let y = read "ONE 2" :: Tests
  print y
  let z = read "TWO 2 5.5" :: Tests
  print z
```

This is output

```
ZERO         
ONE 10       
TWO 1 3.14   
ZERO         
ONE 2        
TWO 2 5.5
```

**Here are questions:**

1. What is recommend way to implement `Read` instance?

   - The minimal complete definition of `Read` class is `readsPrec | readPrec`
     and `readPrec :: ReadPrec a` description wrote

   > Proposed replacement for readsPrec using new-style parsers (GHC only).

   - Should I use `readPrec` instead, How? I can't find any example on the net that I can understand.
   - What is the `new-style parsers`, is it `parsec`?
2. What is the first `Int` argument of [readsPrec :: Int -> ReadS a](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Text-Read.html#v:readsPrec) , is using for?
3. Is there anyway to somehow deriving `Read` from `Show`?

In the past I could use `deriving (Show,Read)` to most of the job. But this time I want to move to next level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In my opinion the correct way to implement Read is to derive it and otherwise, it is likely better to move on to more sophisticated parsers. Here is answers to all of your questions anyways.

   - readPrec is a simple parser combinator based approach for that GHC provides. If you are willing to sacrifice portability for your Read instance you can use it and it makes parsing easier.
   - I include a small example of how you could use readPrec below
   - parsec is different from readPrec, however both are parser combinator like. [Parsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec) is a much more complete parser library. Another parser combinator library is [attoparsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec)  which works very similarly to parsec.
   - parsec and attoparsec can't be used with the ordinary Read typeclass (at least directly) but the greater flexibility they offer makes them a good idea for any time you want more complex parsing.
2. The `Int` argument to `readsPrec` is for dealing with precedence when parsing. This might matter when you want to parse arithmetic expressions. You can choose to fail parsing if the precedence is higher than the precedence of the current operator.
3. Deriving `Read` from `Show` isn't possible unfortunately.

Here are a couple of snippets that show how I would implement `Read` using `ReadPrec`.

ReadPrec example:

```
instance Read Tests where
  readPrec = choice [pZero, pOne, pTwo] where
    pChar c = do
      c' <- get
      if c == c'
      then return c
      else pfail
    pZero = traverse pChar "ZERO" *> pure Zero
    pOne = One <$> (traverse pChar "ONE " *> readPrec)
    pTwo = Two <$> (traverse pChar "TWO " *> readPrec) <*> readPrec
```

In general implementing Read is less intuitive than more heavyweight parsers. Depending on what you want to parse I highly suggest learning parsec or attoparsec since they are extremely useful when you want to parse even more complicated things.

Comment: Recommending a fully featured parser for such a simple syntax is a bit silly (like a recommendation to hunt birds with a machine gun). There is no rule that `Show`/`Read` can't be used for customized syntaxes (indeed, any abstract type with a `Show` instance must use a customized syntax). It is the *derived* instances which can't be used to implement a customized syntax, but the OP states they are *not* using the derived instances.

Comment: I edit to numbering the question, if you answering the `1.` can you provide a working code?